# What does an actuator part look like?

Tags: vw, door, jetta

I found out that one of my actuators is broken. I found this part corresponding to the door that needs to be fixed. It's called 'door latch', so not sure if this contains the actuator. I'd appreciate any explanation!

When I looked up 'actuator' for my 2008 VW Jetta S on amazon website, this was the result.

The issue is that the door doesn't lock, so I was told the actuator is broken and the part needs to be replaced.

So I assumed this is the part needs to be replaced for the lock to work.

How can I fix my door lock?

Would this be the correct component to repair it?

[image: latch]

Comment: I would think what you are calling an "actuator" is the part which causes the latch to "unlatch", but I don't know for sure. The slot in the black portion on the left is what latches the door. The plug which is the smallish black thing to the bottom right under the white plastic is the plug. The actuator should be somewhere in between these two parts. The metal thing which is about center is the locking mechanism, I'd think, which prevents the actuator from working if this is engaged. Dunno for sure though.

Comment: It's difficult to tell how this particular switching device might work.  When you are talking about a 'door' is this for an air-circulation door in your AC system or an actual door.  If you include the manufacturer of the part and the part number that could be helpful.  As well, what make/model/year of car.  Some more specifics will help someone who wants to answer the question.

Comment: You have now changed your question into shopping assistance.  So sorry.  Check out this overview of how a QA site works.   http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tour    I'm going to edit your question and take out the shopping assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An actuator is an electo-mechanical part.  If you take apart your door, it will likely be a small plastic box with power supplied to it, and will have a plunger that moves in/out when door is electronically or physically locked/unlocked.  In your image, it looks like that piece may be integrated directly into to the door latch shown (since there is a electical connection shown). Since it might be integrated (if that part is for your car), that could be the correct part. However in other cars it is a separate item and may be found in other locations.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have seen what an actuator looks like and it's much smaller than the product in the image, so I wasn't sure if it was included in that part. How can I know that for my car, the actuator is in this part?

Comment: If that part is listed as being the correct part for your vehicle, then get it. It has the actuator inside.

Comment: It likely looks like this on the inside: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5dtdyDDgrw

Comment: Wow, that's a great video. So many youtube videos where you have people without a clue.